# Oracle12c:Trigger created with compilation errors(table or view does not exist)

Tags: oracle, triggers, oracle12c

I try to create a trigger as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER update_student
AFTER UPDATE OF school ON student FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE school SET num2=num2+1 WHERE school.id=(SELECT school FROM inserted);
END;
/
```

But When I execute the code,it shows `Trigger created with compilation errors`,and then I execute `show errors;`,it shows me as follows:

```
2/5 PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
2/71 PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

I guess the table here means school,but I am sure that table `school` exists.Where is the problem lies?Please give me a hand.Thanks!

I have modified the code as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER update_student
AFTER UPDATE OF school ON student FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE :new.school SET num2=num2+1 WHERE school.id=(SELECT :new.school FROM inserted);
END;
/
```

But new error occurred.It shows:

```
2/5      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
2/24     PL/SQL: ORA-00903: invalid table name
```

How can I fix it?Thanks!

Comment: What is this? `(SELECT school FROM inserted)` - looks like maybe SQL Server syntax?  Won't work in Oracle.  Use `:new.school` instead

Comment: @TonyAndrews Thanks!But new problem occurred.I have added it to the question.Can you help me?Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a trigger you should use the :NEW and :OLD pseudo-rows to access the new and old field values. As such, your UPDATE statement should be:

```
UPDATE school
  SET num2 = num2 + 1
  WHERE school.id = :NEW.SCHOOL;
```

You might also want to decrement the count of students at the old school:

```
UPDATE SCHOOL
  SET NUM2 = NUM2 - 1
  WHERE SCHOOL.ID = :OLD.SCHOOL;
```

And you should probably avoid trying to update a SCHOOL row if STUDENT.SCHOOL (either the old or new versions) are NULL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER UPDATE_STUDENT
  AFTER UPDATE OF SCHOOL ON STUDENT
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :NEW.SCHOOL IS NOT NULL THEN
    UPDATE SCHOOL
      SET NUM2 = NUM2 + 1
      WHERE SCHOOL.ID = :NEW.SCHOOL;
  END IF;

  IF :OLD.SCHOOL IS NOT NULL THEN
    UPDATE SCHOOL
      SET NUM2 = NUM2 - 1
      WHERE SCHOOL.ID = :OLD.SCHOOL;
  END IF;
END UPDATE_STUDENT;
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I am sorry that my carelessness led to the problem